# Laravel return error on duplicate column in CSV using maatwebsite/excel

Tags: laravel, csv

I have code which i am using to import a CSV using the `maatwebsite/excel` package in Laravel.

I am importing to a collection, but before that i am using the `rules` method to run some validation.

I have the following validation rule to check the DB for user id's that already exist.

```
'user_id' => ['required', 'unique:user,id', 'string', 'max:60'],
```

But I also want to check that the same user id does not appear multiple times in the same column of the actual CSV file.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this:

```
'user_id' => ['required', 'unique:your_csv_table_name,user_id', 'string', 'max:60'],
```

Comment: That would check the DB though yeh? ... Im wanting to actually check the CSV itself

Comment: @CodeSauce, I don't know about  `maatwebsite/excel` how it works. But I can't answer without seeing your code and what data you get.

Comment: I think do not want to store duplicate records that why you want to check it in csv file ?

Comment: @AbdulHaseebKhan correct

Answer (score 0):

I use `updateOrCreate` function to avoid duplicate records https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#upserts

```
$flight = Flight::updateOrCreate(
    ['departure' => 'Oakland', 'destination' => 'San Diego'],
    ['price' => 99, 'discounted' => 1]
);
```